# Proving uniform convergence using Dini's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, uniform-convergence

let $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ bounded and continuos, and let (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$) $f_{n}(x)=\sup\{f(y):y\in[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]\}.$

prove that $f_{n}\rightrightarrows$ f on every proper and bounded interval on $\mathbb{R}$

so long I have tried using Dini's theorem. of course that $f_{n}$ is monotonically increasing, and it is easy to prove the pointwise convergence, but I cant grasp the idea of proving that every (or almost every $f_{n}$) is continuous.

thank you!

Comment: $f_n(x)$ is decreasing with respect to $n$ and $f_n(x)\to f(x).$ Still instead of applying Dini's theorem it is simpler to use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on every bounded interval. In this way we avoid verifying that $f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous can help me get a uniform $\epsilon$ to bound the difference between the function and the $f_n$'s?